# How do you read a file from Azure Blob w/ Apache Spark without Databricks but with wasbs on Windows 10?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage

I have azure-storage-8.6.0.jar and hadoop-azure-3.0.1.jar. I keep seeing from other forums that I have to modify the core-site.xml file in the etc folder in hadoop like so https://github.com/hning86/articles/blob/master/hadoopAndWasb.md. I didn't know I even needed to download all of hadoop to run Spark. I thought all I needed was the winutils.exe in hadoop/bin.

```
    spark.read.load(f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/myfile.txt" )



Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.load.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Accepted. I spent hours doing this and even downloaded the whole spark file from apache. It's just hard making sure files are in the right place and that env variables are set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use pyspark to read CSV file from Azure blob storage on Windows 10, please refer to the following steps

1. Install pyspark

```
pip install pyspark
```

2. Code (create .py file)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import traceback

try:

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net',
                   '<account key>')
    df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(
        'wasbs://<container name>@<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory name>/<file name>')
    df.show()

except Exception as exp:
    print("Exception occurred")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

3. Run code

```
cd <your python or env path>\Scripts
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.5 <your py file path>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it except I use sas token instead of account key for authentication and I run just "spark-submit my_script.py" since I have the 2 jars on the path somehow.